# How to modify existing REST web service to work with SSL

Tags: vb.net, web-services, rest, ssl

I have the following simple REST service running based on the code found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412178(v=vs.110).aspx) - code below.
How can I modify this to be able to use transport security - SSL ?
I've been googling around for a solution, but it seems that most examples are mentioning to modify web.config file, but this example doesn't even have that... Thanks for any help with this one!

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Text

<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IService
    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebGet()> _
    Function EchoWithGet(ByVal s As String) As String

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke()> _
    Function EchoWithPost(ByVal s As String) As String
  end interface

Public Class Service
    Implements IService
    Public Function EchoWithGet(ByVal s As String) As String Implements IService.EchoWithGet
        Return "You said " + s
    End Function

    Public Function EchoWithPost(ByVal s As String) As String Implements IService.EchoWithPost
        Return "You said " + s
    End Function
End Class

Module program

    Sub Main()
        Dim host As WebServiceHost = New WebServiceHost(GetType(Service), New Uri("http://localhost:8000/"))
        Try
            Dim ep As ServiceEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IService), New WebHttpBinding(), "")
            host.Open()
            Using cf As New ChannelFactory(Of IService)(New WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8000")

                cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New WebHttpBehavior())

                Dim channel As IService = cf.CreateChannel()

                Dim s As String

                Console.WriteLine("Calling EchoWithGet via HTTP GET: ")
                s = channel.EchoWithGet("Hello, world")
                Console.WriteLine("   Output: {0}", s)

                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.WriteLine("This can also be accomplished by navigating to")
                Console.WriteLine("http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet?s=Hello, world!")
                Console.WriteLine("in a web browser while this sample is running.")

                Console.WriteLine("")

                Console.WriteLine("Calling EchoWithPost via HTTP POST: ")
                s = channel.EchoWithPost("Hello, world")
                Console.WriteLine("   Output: {0}", s)
                Console.WriteLine("")
            End Using

            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate")
            Console.ReadLine()

            host.Close()
        Catch cex As CommunicationException
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", cex.Message)
            host.Abort()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following solved my problem and all traffic goes through HTTPS. I hope this will help someone in the future.

```
    Dim binding As New WebHttpBinding

    binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport
    Dim store As New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
    Dim cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost", False)(0)
    store.Close()

    Dim bindPortToCertificate As New Process
    bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "netsh.exe")
    bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0} certhash={1} appid={{{2}}}", 22370, cert.Thumbprint, Guid.NewGuid())
    bindPortToCertificate.Start()
    bindPortToCertificate.WaitForExit()
```